# Pandas dataframes doesn't sort properly

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, sorting

I have a Pandas Dataframe like this [one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJpkB.png)

It was obtained froma sqlite3 query. which included

```
'ORDER BY Total DESC'
```

But as you can see it the dataframe is not sorted by total. I tried `df=df.sort_values('Total',ascending=False)` without any success.

If I use the following workaround

```
df.to_csv("merged/Report_Merged_History.csv",index=False)
df=pd.read_csv("merged/Report_Merged_History.csv")
df=df.sort_values('Total',ascending=False)
```

I have a properly sorted dataframe. (I don't have reputation to post it)

But if I try to save `to_hdf` I can't sort the dataframe.

Here is the dataframe [df.csv](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60128827/Report_Merged_History.csv)

Comment: Are the values in your Total column being read in as strings or numbers?

Comment: The problem could be that the Total column is being treated as string rather than `float`, what does `df.info()` show when you read from the DB? You could do `df['Total'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Total'])` to convert the `dtype` and then `sort_values` should work fine

Comment: Thank you. That was exactly the problem.